# How to set chrome browser window resolution in Jenkins while running protractor script

Tags: jenkins, protractor

I am trying to launch Protractor-cucumber script from Jenkins but while running tests browser size it not getting maximized.

Tried all possible solutions provided and it doesnot work. Below command tried to run from Jenkins window Batch command

```
protractor cucumber.conf.js --capabilities.chromeOptions.args="--safe-mode"   --capabilities.chromeOptions.args="--window-size=1280,1024"
```

Comment: Maybe you have to put all `--capabilities.chromeOptions.args` params withing the same parenthesis as follows: 
`protractor cucumber.conf.js --capabilities.chromeOptions.args="--safe-mode --window-size=1280,1024" `

Or don't you have a protractor.conf.js? You can set chrome options via `capabilities` object. => https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/browser-setup.md

Comment: Hello, Thanks for reply!  I have tried this option through Protractor.config file and worked as expected while running through command line  but when i am running script though Jenkins its not working.

Answer (score 0):

just add in protractor.config this:

```
browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(1600, 1200);
```

with your desired resolution

Comment: I have tried this option through Protractor.config file and worked as expected while running through command line  but when i am running script though Jenkins its not working.                                      
   onPrepare: function() {
      browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(1280, 1024);
   },

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for issue. This problem was due to the way slave machine is set up. Currently Jenkins slave is running as Window services which is creating problem.

When I have stopped this Jenkins slave services and started again from command line with below command then its working fine.

Command: java -jar slave.jar -jnlpUrl https://Jenkins Instance url/slave-agent.jnlp

Thank you very much for comment and support.